# How to find the greatest remainder of a number that is a multiple of another number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> The greatest possible remainder for a multiple of 4 being divided by
>   6, happens when 4 is divided by 6.

I don't understand why the above statement must be true. Is it relying on a well-known fact or property?

I do know that the possible remainders for any number,$x$, when it is divided by 6 is $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ or $5$. However, I am not sure what happens to this rule when we impose additional conditions on $x$.

Comment: What remainders modulo $6$ are possible if $x$ is even?

Comment: The answer is $0,2, 4$, isn't it? I got this from performing the division on the sequence $2, 4, 6, 8, 10, \dots$ and I don't think this is how you wanted me to arrive at the answer...

Comment: Write $x$ as $6\cdot q + r$ with an integer $q$ and an integer $r$ such that $0 \leqslant r \leqslant 5$. Then $r$ is the remainder upon division of $x$ by $6$. No, if $x$ is even, $x = 2k$, then since $6 = 2\cdot 3$, we have $k = \frac{x}{2} = 3\cdot q + \frac{r}{2}$. Thus $\frac{r}{2} = k - 3q$ is an integer, so $r$ must be even. That leaves $r \in \{0,2,4\}$ as possibilities. Easy to check that they all occur. That reasoning generalises, if $x$ is divisible by $d$ and $d$ also divides $m$, then the remainder of $x$ modulo $m$ must be divisible by $d$.